# Embedded Tomcat won't listen to port 80 in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm launching a Spring Boot .jar with Embedded Tomcat to an Elastic Beanstalk (Java) instance.

server.port=80 in the configuration file, however EB won't let Tomcat bind to port 80.

What's preventing Tomcat from listening to port 80 and how do I fix it?

Here's the pertinent section of the logs:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1000) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:980) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:573) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

2017-02-09 09:05:28.126  INFO 2451 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-02-09 09:05:28.156  INFO 2451 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-02-09 09:05:28.167 ERROR 2451 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-02-09 09:05:28.175  INFO 2451 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5387f9e0: startup date [Thu Feb 09 09:05:19 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-09 09:05:28.178  INFO 2451 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: You can run your app with `sudo` as the `ec2-user` is not allowed to bind to port 80. This is not a good practice obviously for security concerns. Why do you want to listen on port 80? Elastic beanstalk by default will proxy to port 8080.

Comment: I have the same issue in using nodejs before. In beanstalk, it uses nginx as proxy server to pass http request to nodejs.

Answer (score 6):

I assume topic starter already resolved this problem, but I'll post my solution here for the new people who'll be stuck on the same issue.

I've made my Spring Boot application accessible from port 80 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk by setting environment property SERVER_PORT to 5000 (you can set it in "Configuration" > "Software Configuration").

Idea taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elas)